# SET woocommerce defaut css BACK

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

EDIT:

I change the css and the rows are there. But now, Ths columns are not with the same size. Anybody can help me?

```
.products { /*****styling products*****/
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;

}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  display: flex; 
}
```

I'm working hard to make my own woocommerce theme, but somehow, I did something that broke the default css and besides everything, I have now a big problem with my shop page, the products are shown in list (as expected), but I only can handle the number of products displayed per page, I can't choose the number by row or column, I couldn't show rows, just one.

I have decided to start over, but my last host is this: **Anybody knows a way to bring the default css back? It could save me tons of work.**

**If I use another theme, everything works.**

My shop: [www.quickgamestore.ml](http://www.quickgamestore.ml)

Answer (score 0):

How did you install your woocommerce? If you uploaded it yourself, you can easliy extract the CSS File you need.

Otherwise, try to get the Template you are using and extract the CSS File there.

Comment: I did it by myself and already check, all woocommerce*.css is there, but it's not loaded. I tryed to remove all my css, and the page became raw, no style added. The strange thing is, is I active another plugin, everything cames with it. I tryed to remove all my functions.php as well, and nothing changes. No style came back.

Comment: I added a plugin to manage and when I try do use, this message shows: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'new_loop_shop_per_page' not found or invalid function name in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 298

Comment: If you go to my shop page now, you can see I could break the row and make another. But now, I can't design the products properly, My images is not always the same size and if my title is bigger than an image widht, it breaks the column. Could you help me? See the EDIT.